# Why is my Elasticsearch 1.6.0 missing the plugin manager?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to run **elasticsearch 1.6.0** using **cygwin on a 64-bit Windows 7** machine. I downloaded the elasticsearch zip from the elasticsearch home page, and installed the latest version of java and **jdk (1.8.0_45)** and have set the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the right path I think. When I try to execute the very first step in the Definitive Guide installation process:

```
$ ./bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager
```

I've seen this problem with earlier versions of elastic, but apparently the problem was fixed so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I tried installing marvel on my windows machine with JRE 1.7 and it works fine. Try moving to 1.7

Comment: Hi, replace ./bin/plugin with ./bin/plugin.bat. That worked for me.